# Ember.js: When is a model accessible to the controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember, when is a model accessible to the controller?

Below is a simple Ember application with a static model and a controller that attempts to access the model on `init`. You'll notice that on `init` the model `title` attribute is `undefined`. However, the setTimeout illustrates that the `model` is later accessible.

I was under the impression that Ember wouldn't initiate the controller until the model is ready. Is this correct? The Ember documentation (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/) indicates that models, even when loaded asynchronously are available when the controller is instantiated.

http://jsfiddle.net/vu263uwq/1/

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return posts[0];
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    alertTitle: function() {
        var that = this;

        jQuery(".output").append("1. "+this.get("title")+"<br />"); //Returns "undefined"

        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(".output").append("2. "+that.get("title")); //Returns the correct title
        }, 1000);
    }.on("init")
});

var posts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "First title",
        body: "Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam."
    },{
        id: 2,
        title: "Second title",
        body: "Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum."
    }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your impression is actually wrong. The setupController hook is where you set any properties on the controller, including the model. Actually, all `setupController` does by default is set the model on the controller. That's why if you override the hook and still need the `model` set, you must explicitly set the model or make a call to `this._super(controller, model)`.

Notice the signature for setupController:

```
setupController: function(controller, model)
```

In order for this to work, the controller must already be instantiated by the point where Ember sets the model. Init is fired during the instantiation of the controller. So a call to `init` happens before a `model` is set`

As for the asynchronous fetching of models, if your model hook returns a promise, Ember will block until a fulfilled promise can be passed into the `setupController` function so that the model is assigned to the promise's fulfillment and not the promise itself. It lets you avoid calls like:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){  
   var self = this;
   makeAsyncCallReturningPromise().then(function(result){
       self._super(controller, result);
   }
}
```

which would basically accomplish the same thing

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L981 - is the place where controller instantiated. :)

Comment: @Microfed ah, I corrected my post. I meant init is called when the controller is instantiated, which happens before the call to `this.setupController(controller, context, transition);`

Comment: @sunrize920 Is there an event that would trigger a function, within the controller, when the model is available? Such as `.on("ready")` or something of that nature? Is there a reason that a controller is instantiated prior to the model being available? Seems odd, as a Controller depends on it. Just curious.

Comment: you could have a function `.observes('model')` which would fire anytime the model changes, including the first time its added. You could also invoke a function in the controller inside setupController on the route with `controller.someFunction()` What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The code you've written in your jsfiddle is not very "Ember" at all

Comment: Simply learning; I don't have a specific project or task I am trying to accomplish at this time except going through the Ember guide. I just made the JSFiddle as a simple example to illustrate my point.